# ClassCastException in Mockito for jdbcTemplate query

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to test a class in a Spring project. I have the following methods

```
public List<Range> getRanges() {
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(RANGE_SQL, new RangeMapper());
}

public List<Score> getScores() {
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(SCORE_SQL, new ScoreMapper());
}

public Map<String, Object> getData() {
    //other code
    final List<Range> ranges = getRanges();
    final List<Score> scores = getScores();
}
```

In test case for `getData()`-

```
when(jdbcTemplate.query(any(String.class), any(RangeMapper.class))).thenReturn(rangeList);
when(jdbcTemplate.query(any(String.class), any(ScoreMapper.class))).thenReturn(scoresList);
```

when I run the test for `getData`, it's failing with `ClassCastException` stating *"Score cannot be cast to Range"*. When i debug and see, `getRanges()` in `getData()` is returning `scoresList`. Why is this happening and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to mock the `getRanges()` and the `getScores()` methods instead.

```
when(theClass.getScores()).thenReturn(scoresList);
when(theClass.getRanges()).thenReturn(rangesList);
```

If you need to do it your way you should specify the string to get the right result:

```
when(jdbcTemplate.query(SCORE_SQL, any(ScoreMapper.class))).thenReturn(scoresList);
when(jdbcTemplate.query(RANGE_SQL, any(RangeMapper.class))).thenReturn(rangesList);
```

The specification `any(String.class)` is the breaking point here. In your case you've got the problem that you haven't specified in which case it returns the right thing.

So if you specify the given `String` it should return the right `List`